# custom login page redirect to logged in user profile page

Tags: login, buddypress, wp-login-form

If I click on **sign in** then it should go to the login page.

The issue is that when I put the link then it goes to `redirect_to` home page, but I want to go on user profile page instead.

I don't want to use a plugin to redirect to profile page after login.

I have code for user profile - `<a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain(); ?>/profile/edit/"><span>My Profile</span></a>`

And i want to put this link into `<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_attr($redirect_to); ?>" />`

Is this possible? Are there other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply....                              I tried with this code and put in bp-child->function.php  but still it goes to home page. And my profile link is look like this "www.mysite.com/members/%username%/profile/edit"

Comment: Since you are using a custom login page it is hard to guess what is happening. Post your code please.

Comment: I have another issue with this log in page when I click on activation link in mail after registration page, it goes to wp-login page so that I want to change with custom login page and then it goes to member profile page.

Comment: Maybe you do have multiple issues but that doesn't get me any closer to understanding the problem. ___Post your code.___

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. Do you need code of custom login page or fuction.php?

Comment: I need the _relevant_ code. I don't know where that code is.

Comment: You're gonna need to click "Edit" on your original question and add in the above code. Most people don't look at comments but the question itself. [Get Formatting Help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: cant you use header function ?
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built in function to create the login box, one of the parameters is redirect. [wp_login_form function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)

To get your profile link, check when you're logged in as admin. The link is the same, but the options presented are different. Default is yoursite.com/wp-admin/profile.php

Answer (score 0):

You can write code in function in `functions.php` and add action to this

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_rd', 10, 3 );

Function my_rd(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[IF you wants to use plguin bp redirect to profile go here:](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-redirect-to-profile/)

```
add_filter( 'bp_login_redirect', 'bpdev_redirect_to_profile', 11, 3 );

function bpdev_redirect_to_profile( $redirect_to_calculated, $redirect_url_specified, $user ){

    if( empty( $redirect_to_calculated ) )
        $redirect_to_calculated = admin_url();

    //if the user is not site admin,redirect to his/her profile

    if( isset( $user->ID) && ! is_super_admin( $user->ID ) )
        return bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->ID );
    else
        return $redirect_to_calculated; /*if site admin or not logged in,do not do anything much*/

}
```